# Scrolling down UIScrollView when selecting upper UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I am having a ScrollView, with a ContentView, which has 5 UITextFields. I have implemented adjustForKeyboard:

```
func adjustForKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convertRect(keyboardScreenEndFrame, fromView: view.window)

    if notification.name == UIKeyboardWillHideNotification {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    } else {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height, right: 0)
    }

    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = scrollView.contentInset

}
```

Of course I have set up the observers:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // Add observers for keyboard
    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "adjustForKeyboard:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "adjustForKeyboard:", name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
}
```

It works fine when I select the TextFields from up to down but when I select an upper TextField, it moves just a few pixels. How should I change my method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the bottom contentInset will not make the scrollView scroll.  It sets a buffer at the bottom, so if you scroll all the way to the bottom it will have more room to scroll.

You want to modify the contentOffset of the scrollView and animate the contentOffset change.  You'd do something like this:

```
var contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
contentOffset.y = contentOffset.y + (however much you want it to move)
scrollView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: true)
```

That will let it scroll both up and down depending which textField is selected.

Comment: So I don't need the if-else based on the notification type?

Comment: And how much should I move it? keyboardViewEndFrame.height or keyboardScreenEndFrame.height maybe?

Comment: This is just an example how / what to modify.  You'll need to do a different contentOffset for the show and hide case, since you probably want the state to be different.  I have no idea how much you should move it, it depends what you're trying to do.

Comment: But the value shouldn't be hard-coded, should it? It has to be something related to the keyboard I think...

Comment: Yes, it will be.  What I've done in the past is used `keyboardFrame.origin.y` to figure out the topmost point of the keyboard, and then do a bunch of math to figure out where I want the keyboard to be in relation to it.  

A helpful method to get everything in the right system is `textField.convertPoint(textField.origin.y, toView: UIWindow.mainWindow)`  (theres a couple helper methods in there but thats the gist of it)

Comment: Thank you very much for your tips, I'll try them.